# Отступы внутри ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Они используются дляя отступа между Item! Но мне нужно сделать отступ поменьше В Item то есть внутри паддинг уменьшить, подскажите пожалуйста...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вам надо создать свой вариант разметки для элемента и в нём задать нужные вам параметры. Вы, видимо, используете простейший адаптер из коробки, в конструктор коего передаёте встроенный же ресурс разметки. Вот его и замените на описанный вами в `res/layout` файл, содержащий нужным образом сформированный `TextView`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!